# How to force hyphenation in TextView? (character "-" on word split)

Tags: android, textview, hyphenation

I'm using a TextView extension class which writes a String like a typewriter, character per character. It works fine but when is writing a word which not fit in the current line, it makes a annoying behaviour and deletes the non fitting workd from the current line and writes it into the next line.

I need to know how to tell a TextView to use Hyphenation, it must force word breaks like this:

```
superlargewo-
rd

verylarg-
eword
```

It means putting character - instead of passing the word to the next line

How can that be force into TextView?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hyphenationFrequency is all that `TextView` itself offers, AFAIK.

Comment: well, tryed with introTextView.setHyphenationFrequency(Layout.HYPHENATION_FREQUENCY_FULL); but not working at all. Same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking how to make hyphen work quickly via xml,
this worked for me under SDK 25+

Add `hyphenationFrequency` and hypen `\u00AD` into your String in xml layout like this.

before

```
android:text="Sylabe: "
```

after

```
 android:text="Sy\u00ADla\u00ADbe: "
 android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
```

make sure nothing is set to limit lines of text

```
 android:singleLine="false"
```

It results in following text depending on space:

```
Sylabe
```

or

```
Sy-
labe
```

or

```
Syla-
be
```

notes:
`\u200B` breaks text without any hyphen.