# Breaking lines at soft hyphens

Tags: android, xml, text, line-breaks

I have added soft hyphen signs to all of my strings, yet android breaks the lines at entirely different points. Is there a way to breack the lines only at the points with either a soft hyphen or a space?

Please note that I want to target API 21 and above, so using breakStrategy or hyphenation frequency is not a solution.

None of these questions/answers worked for me:
[Hyphenation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454911/hyphenation-in-android)

[Android:- How to add Hyphen "-" in word break android TextView below 6.0 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280038/android-how-to-add-hyphen-in-word-break-android-textview-below-6-0-os)

[How to force hyphenation in TextView? (character "-" on word split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215037/how-to-force-hyphenation-in-textview-character-on-word-split)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"` to your textview

Answer (score 1):

To make it working use soft hyphen **\u00AD** in strings, e.g.:

`<string name="einzelfahrt_name">Einzelfahrrad\u00ADkarte</string>`

and in your TextView add:

```
android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` to break your string. Try this way.

```
<string name="your_string_name">I want to break after this\nIt's working fine</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, but theres one problem: Depending on screen size, the line will break at different points. If I put `\n` on all those places, I´ll have too many breaks. I´m looking for a way to say "If you break the line, break it only at the points where there is a (soft) hyphen."